# Where in the NetBeans 6.9.1 source code is the code for scanning Java files and finding all the methods, variables, imports etc

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9, automated-refactoring

I'm looking for a sample or possibly even code I can use which scans Java files and tells me key pieces of information about each class, which i can then use much like the NetBeans refactoring and go to source features do.

Comment: Could you please describe what problem you actually are trying to solve?

Comment: I can tell you this: Attempting to separate the parser in Netbeans to something standalone is going to be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: so any recommendations for a similar quality parser library that i can embed in Java?  And why do you say it will be a lot of trouble.  I'm assuming the code is structured well enough so they have a few classes which parse the files and generate the meta data, and others that use the meta data for re-factoring etc. But maybe i shouldn't assume that lol.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reusing the Netbeans sources, you should probably just find a good library.

> tells me key pieces of information about each class

Depending on your definition of "key pieces", I would recommend QDox:

http://qdox.codehaus.org/

> QDox is a high speed, small footprint
>   parser for extracting
>   class/interface/method definitions
>   from source files complete with
>   JavaDoc @tags.

Comment: This looks promising.  Does it support the level of detail used by NetBeans refactoring tools.  Ie. finding variables and code inside methods?  If it does then it sounds like what i'm looking for.

Comment: No, it does not look into methods. In this case you need a full java parser, like eclipse jdt or maybe this one http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/ (never used it, dont know if its good)

Comment: hence why i was looking at the NetBeans source since i know it can already do it.  I need something robust and extensible with a good starting point.  So any ideas about the NetBeans one?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for reusing Netbeans code which parses Java file, I don't know.

If you are looking for how to parse a Java file, you can try [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). ANTLR is a parser generator. There exists [Java grammar](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g) which you can use right away. Once, you generate a Java parser, you can use the parser to parse your Java file. You will have to learn how to use ANTLR.

Comment: I'm looking for a library preferably with source but not necessary as long as it's free that i can embed in my java app.  Can i do that with ANTLR?

Comment: You can embed ANTLR to you java application. Making ANTLR gramar is difficult but using it is easy. The only reason I recommend ANTLR is that there exists Java grammar. Many open-source library use ANTLR to parse their syntax, e.g. HP N3 parser, some SQL parsers.

Comment: You might want to ask for other people opinion about ANTLR before actually using it. Some like it, some not. I only like it when i don't need to write the gramma myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your question.

If you want to navigate inside source java code with netbeans, push CTRL and with your mouse go over the word you want to explore ; netbeans highligth the word, and if you clic you go to the source.

Comment: No, i know how to use it, but i want to either write my own for my own application of reuse the NetBeans source code which can parse Java files and generate the necessary meta data about the classes.  Ie. I need a way to get all that meta data about Java files.